# AWS Eventbridge Pipe not working for SQS FIFO queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

I have an Eventbridge pipe from Kinesis as source to SQS Fifo as target.

The event payload within Kinesis looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "object": {...},
        "mode": "U",
        "sfId": "0035E00003H2M8BQAV",
        "eventName": "STATE_CHANGED_EVENT",
        "id": "0035E00003H2M8BQAV"
    },
    "id": "a7294470-171c-41ba-b2a9-52366fef201f",
    "source": "...",
    "specversion": "0.3",
    "type": "STATE_CHANGED_EVENT",
    "time": "2023-09-05T12:34:58.801Z",
    "datacontenttype": "application/json"
}
```

My Cloudformation looks like this:

```
  ccmsPipe:
    Type: "AWS::Pipes::Pipe"
    DependsOn: SQSQueue
    Properties:
      Name: integration-pipe
      RoleArn: !GetAtt "PipeRole.Arn"
      Source: !Sub arn:aws:kinesis:...
      SourceParameters:
        KinesisStreamParameters:
          StartingPosition: "LATEST"
          BatchSize: 1
        FilterCriteria:
          Filters: []
      Target: !GetAtt "SQSQueue.Arn"
      TargetParameters:
        SqsQueueParameters:
          MessageDeduplicationId: "$.data.id"
          MessageGroupId: "$.data.data.sfId"
        InputTemplate: >
          {
            "object": <$.data.data.object>,
            "eventName": <$.data.data.eventName>,
            "id": <$.data.data.id>,
            "mode": <$.data.data.mode>
          }
```

The SQS Queue is FIFO. Every invocation of the pipe fails and i have no idea why. Is there at least a possibility to get the error message of the Pipe? In the monitoring i only see "TargetStageFailed".

Comment: Once i added ```MaximumRecordAgeInSeconds: 3600``` to the ```KinesisStreamParameters```, it started working. This sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Possible cause for your issue could be related to this:

> If you specify a `DeadLetterConfig` for a pipe with a Kinesis or
> DynamoDB source, make sure that the `MaximumRecordAgeInSeconds` property
> on the pipe is less than the `MaximumRecordAge` of the source event.

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-error-troubleshooting.html#eb-pipes-dlq-behavior)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but the current configuration is currently 72 hours for the MaximumRecordAgeInSeconds and 24 hours for the MaximumRecordAge (RetentionPeriod in Kinesis) and it works.